# How to check if a given data exists in multiple tables(all different column names)

Tags: mysql

I have a database where there are 6 different tables (Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Theta, Epsilon, Pi) and there is a users table where one user can be in a different role inside the tables.
He can be director of Alpha and Faculty in Beta.

the column names are different in each table(Director, Faculty, Member, Advisor, Student etc)

I need a mysql query which will check if a particular is present in one or more tables against his role.

Thank You.

Comment: Without table structures, sample data, attempted solutions, why those didn't work and the desired results, this question is not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a table structure, it is difficult to give answers. But assuming you have a user master table and different role based tables you can do the following

```
  select user.id, a.director, b.faculty, c.member, d.advisor, e.student, f.user from user
    left join alpha a on user.id = a.director
    left join beta b on user.id = b.faculty
    left join gama c on user.id = c.member
    left join ththa d on user.id = d.advisor
    left join epsilon e on user.id = e.student
    left join pi f on user.id = f.user
```

Answer (score 1):

this piece of code worked for me.....

```
SELECT * FROM table1 h,table2 u,table3 s WHERE h.col1='$search_text' OR u.col1='$search_text' OR s.col1='$search_text'
```

hope it help u